# How can i duplicate order by quote?

Tags: magento-1.9, edit-order

I need duplicate order, I know i will need convert old order to qoute but i cant convert quote to new order.

Comment: that is a great question and I am really curious to know, I think you can get help of order edit, because when you edit an order, it will be cancled and a new order willl be generated which is similar to the old one in so many values.

Comment: Please share code..